# How i can read a file using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, quartz-scheduler

I have a zipped CSV file.

I have some quartz job schedular which reads the file. But sometimes the user can click and read the file also. Is it possible that if during the user operation file is open and then the quartz job schedular also starts and it also starts reading the file and as it's a zipped CSV file something may become corrupted.

Special Note : There is no write operation to the file.

Comment: how big is the file? can the job make a copy and read the copy?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the same file in as many threads as you like.

It will only be corrupted if you write it in one thread and try to use it in another at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to read the same file simultaneously from several threads. Just create separate `FileInputStream` for each thread.

Comment: @user882196 In each thread use `new FileInputStream(file)` just as you would in one thread.

Comment: u mean do like new Thread and inside each thread create new instance of InputStream . But this way i need to take of each streams otherwise there will be overflow of streams.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no write operation on your file then you will have no problem in reading it.

You can read it in all your threads.

Problem will come if you try to write it.

Even you can avoid this problem by making your File object Synchronized.